# Search SQL query from multiple tables MySQL

Tags: mysql, search

I am trying to perform search on multiple tables.

I will simplify problem and say that I have 2 tables `Worker` and `Customer` both have `Id, Name, Surname` and `Worker` has additional `Position`, all fields are `varchar` except `Id` which is `Int`.

How to make a query that will return rows of either `Customer` or `Worker`, where one of theirs fields contains entered search string.

I have tried with joins but I got returned joined row also.

Comment: For some reason I was thinking that I cant use union because fields do not exactly match. I was wrong, thanks.

Comment: Take a look at my example. It suffices to add an "empty" field in order to match the number.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
select id,name,surname,position,'worker' as tbl from worker where ..
union all
select id,name,surname,'','customer' from customer where ...
```

In this way you can even know results what table belong to.

Answer (score 4):

Just `UNION` both queries.
If you really can `JOIN` those two, you can use
an `IF` statement in the `SELECT` clause to show the right field.
But, from what I understand from your question, go with `UNION`